# PHP - Variable from form not staying after refresh, or not appearing at all

Tags: php

I am testing PHP and the variable from the form is not staying, and does not appear even on the same page. Here is the code:

```
<?php
echo "<form action='input.php' method='post'>Test: <input type='text' name='last' </form><input type=submit>";
echo "<h1>The last input was: </h1>", $_POST["last"];
?>
```

Comment: @MrRubix: Huh? The HTML is right there in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a PHP problem. It is an HTML problem.

Your submit button is outside of the form.

It's effectively "submitting" a blank, empty, made-up form of its own.

That made-up form does not contain any of your data.

**Move the submit button to inside of the form.**

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't think of that.

Comment: @TheZipCreator: You also forgot the end of your text box tag.